# removing brackets in json using Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to remove the {} from the series ID.

```
  "seriesID" : "CUUR0000SA0"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "CUSR0000SA0"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "LNS14000000"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "CES0000000001"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "CUUR0000SA0L1E"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "CES0500000003"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "WPUFD4"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "LNS12000000"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "WPSFD4"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "CUSR0000SA0L1E"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "WPUFD49104"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "WPSFD49104"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "LNS13000000"
}, {
  "seriesID" : "LNS11300000"
}, {
```

i tried using a jolt and a replace text in NIFI but i am not able to remove these brackets, anything helps

Comment: What would you like your output to be? An array of the values corresponding to the seriesID values? Or a single object with multiple seriesID fields in it? The latter is not valid JSON (keys must have unique values) so it wouldn't work in Jolt

Comment: i would like the output to look like this 


"seriesID":"CUUR0000SA0",
"seriesID":"CUSR0000SA0",
"seriesID":"LNS14000000",
"seriesID":"CES0000000001",
seriesID":"CUUR0000SA0L1E",
"seriesID":"CES0500000003",
"seriesID":"WPUFD4",
"seriesID":"LNS12000000",
"seriesID":"WPSFD4",
"seriesID":"CUSR0000SA0L1E",
"seriesID":"WPUFD49104",
"seriesID":"WPSFD49104",
"seriesID":"LNS13000000",
"seriesID":"LNS11300000",
"seriesID":"CES0500000012"

Comment: i want to lose the {}

Comment: That's not a valid json. Think about converting it to an array: `"seriesID":[ "001", "002", ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a JSON library as the result is not valid JSON. Without array brackets around the input, that is not valid JSON either.

If you had array brackets around the input, you could use the ConvertRecord processor and choose a FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter. There you can choose to output things like:

`"seriesID": "${seriesID}",`

Which will give you what you described in the output (except for the extra comma at the end).

Alternatively you should be able to replace something like `\n}, {` with `,` in ReplaceText, although you will likely need another ReplaceText to get rid of the very first and last curly braces.

Lastly, you could always use ExecuteScript to read in the input and write it out as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is not valid for Jolt transformation, I can suggest you 2 possible solution for your query with Jolt :
Input :

```
[
  {
    "seriesID": "CUUR0000SA0"
  },
  {
    "seriesID": "CUSR0000SA0"
  }
]
```

1. To add additional number in each seriesID key to differentiate it from one another eg seriesID1,seriesID2.

Spec for this :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "seriesID": "seriesID&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

2. To create a Json array with seriesID with all values in it.

   ```
    [{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "seriesID": "seriesID.[&1]"
      }
    }}]
   ```

[image]